# Add Icon to button in odoov8 Tree View

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-view

I need to add Icon to the button in a tree view

```
<button name="gen_link" type="object" icon="/custom_module/static/src/img/image.png" string="MyButton"/>
```

but as I inspect element in browser its shows me

```
<button type="button" class="" title="MyButton">
    <img alt="MyButton" src="http://localhost:8000/web/static/src/img/icons//custom_module/static/src/img/image.png.png">
</button>
```

By default it always takes the default path, I am not able to give custom path for the icon.

Any Suggestion. . .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/..` to move up `/web/static/src/img/icons//` directory.

Insert your button like this (*tested*):

```
<button name="gen_link" 
        type="object" 
        icon="/../../../../../../custom_module/static/src/img/image"/>
```

Comment: Try this solution.